# Using an array as a member variable in a class

Tags: data-modeling, typescript

I have a style question for designing a class to represent a real model.

Let's say I have `Guide` that has `PointsOfInterest` as a member.

Would I want to do something like:

```
class Guide {
    public points: PointsOfInterest[];
}
```

This seems bad, because let's say I've fetched a Guide from my back-end. To add a POI I append it to the array, serialize it, and save it. I'm not sure why but it makes me uneasy exposing the underlying implementation like that.

However, it seems super extra to do something like

```
class Guide {
    public addPointOfInterest(poi: PointOfInterest): boolean;
    public removePointOfInterest(idOfPoi: string): boolean;
    public iterateOnPointsOfInterest((poi: Poi) => any): boolean;
}
```

I think I am overthinking this, but I feel like this is a very common design question and it would be nice to be pointed to resources where I can learn about patterns for data modeling.

Also, I've been reading about immutable data structures and I was wondering how that would play in here.

Comment: "uneasy exposing the underlying implementation like that." Estimate the probability of actually ever changing this implementation detail, called it `P`. Estimate the time it would take to refactor this, call it `T`. If implementing this abstraction takes longer than `P * T`, then you shouldn't waste your time with it.

Comment: Another option is to create a read-only wrapper class around arrays that allows only non-mutating operations; then, for accessing the array from outside `Guide`, you can provide a simple getter that just wraps the internal array in the new class. This is the approach provided by languages like Java and Swift, or effectively provided by languages with true mutability rules like Rust or C++, and it's generally a best practice for API design; JavaScript/Typescript's standard libraries unfortunately don't help with this task at all.

Answer (score 1):

What if I write code that adds a point of interest? Would you need to save that information somewhere? Would that happen if I just add the point? What would I have to do to add a point of interest and make sure that this is processed properly?

Your two methods addPoint, removePoint are fine. Instead of iterating, you might have a method that returns a copy of the points array (so if there is multi-threaded access, the caller knows he or she gets a copy that was valid at the time of call but may not be the latest state a millisecond later). The caller can do the iterating themselves, but is more flexible. And of course that doesn't mean you have to implement this as an array internally; that's your own business.